# ng-class toggling not working with 2 different expressions toggling same class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have a situation where I want the class `.opened` to be added to both the $first item and when another condition is met.

`ng-class="{opened:$first,opened:visited_place.id == lastClickedVisitedPlace}"`

Both of these expressions work well on their own but when combined like above, the first one fails... can someone explain to me how I can fix this?

I've tried using multiple ng-class attributes but it gives me an error saying there can be only 1 ng-class attribute on an element.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using:**

```
ng-class="{opened:$first || visited_place.id == lastClickedVisitedPlace}"
```

Here's a working fiddle that models your desired result, I believe. In this case, the class `.opened` is applied if a div is `$first` OR if `$index == 3`: https://jsfiddle.net/c1huchuz/31/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
ng-class="{opened:$first || visited_place.id == lastClickedVisitedPlace}"
```

From [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name.